# Creating two separate filter chain flows

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, struts-1

I'm trying to create two separate filter chain flows in struts 1. If a parameter has a certain value, it will go down one filter chain. Otherwise, it will go down the other one.

For example, in [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzbcW.jpg), if the parameter a from filter 2 is true the filter chain will go 1->2->3->4->5->9. If the parameter a from filter 2 is false, the filter chain will go 1->2->6->7->8->9.

The only way I can think of to tackle this is to stack all these filters linearly, and depending on the value of a to skip 3,4,5 or 6,7,8.

Has anyone tried to do something similar? Thanks.

Comment: A filter chain is just that, a chain, they execute in order. There's no mechanism (at least there wasn't, it's been awhile) to allow configuration-/rule-based flow changes. Easiest would be to set a flag and just query on that flag. If it's set, don't run the given filter.

Comment: That's what I figured...thanks!